# Maven: how to do parallel builds?

Tags: maven-2, build-process, build-automation

When you build with maven on a multicore / multi-CPU machine it would often be possible to build different subprojects in parallel. Is there a way to do this with maven? Is there a plugin for this / whatever?

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Maven 3 (as of beta 1) now supports parallel builds as an experimental feature.

For example,

```
mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads
mvn -T 1C clean install # 1 thread per cpu core
mvn -T 1.5C clean install # 1.5 thread per cpu core
```

Full documentation can be found on the Maven wiki: [Parallel builds in Maven 3 - Apache Maven - Apache Software Foundation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3).

Comment: What does _1.5_ threads mean? If I have a single core system, does that mean 1 thread, but a dual core system results in 3 threads?

Comment: @SaadMalik Yes, exactly, 3 threads on dual core, 6 threads on quad core systems, etc.

Comment: Is there a argument we can use for the JVM, so we can use this in eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse support does not invoke maven externally.

Comment: Does `mvn -T 2C clean install` do the same trick?  Can we modify this numbers? Can I use `-T 99C` and mvn will use max of my CPU cores? How to calculate optimum?

Comment: What the point in using more that 1 thread per CPU?

Comment: @Enbugger some tests may cause threads to partially idle during tests, for example when waiting for endpoint or database responses.

Answer (score 36):

The suggested solutions are great, but I wanted to add something to the answers here regarding the **test stability during parallel builds**.

So, when [Maven parallel build](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) is used:

```
mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads
mvn -T 1C clean install # 1 thread per cpu core
mvn -T 1.5C clean install # 1.5 thread per cpu core
```

Some **issues with tests** can appear. Note any behavior in tests which is different between serial and parallel test execution. Most of the times it happens do to **improper test isolation resource-wise**.

For example, `test1` manipulate db entry with key `12345`, which is hard-coded and `test2` uses the same entry! It can't be good…

It's a situation that should be considered in the first place, but sometime it's forgotten and could lead to different problems once the switch to parallel maven build is made.

In case that happens, and you still want to use the parallel execution at least in some of the occasions, you can (of course, besides trying to fix the test and make them properly isolated) to [disable Maven test runs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html) using `-DskipTests` argument:

```
mvn clean install -T 4 -DskipTests
```

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

Comment: This is not the point of the question and it isn't good advice. Tests that break in parallel execution are bad tests, They may also be signaling bad code design. It is better to listen and act on it. Skipping tests to solve this is just sweeping something under the rug.

Comment: How it's related? When someone introduces parallel execution in his tests, *it can happen*. It's just pragmatism.

Comment: When running parallel builds, their test phases are also parallel, therefore make sure the debugging is disabled, as the allocation of the debug port breaks silently the parallel builds.

Answer (score 13):

Some of the CI build applications (e.g. hudson) can build multiple maven projects at the same time (and even on multiple machines).

Support for this in maven 'standalone' would also be nice, a quick look through the maven issue tracker gave me: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3004

Comment: I think the Hudson functionality for multiple maven projects at the same time is broken as is indicated in the MNG-3004 JIRA comments.

Comment: Site offline, please check.

Answer (score 4):

If you came to this question looking to sort out your build server and you're not using one that deals with maven natively the magic flag you are looking for is this:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=someNoneGlobalDir
```

do that for each one of your builds and you can let them run all at the same time rather than having everything that uses maven in a queue!