# Maven 3 parallel builds profile

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a way to configure parallel build in Maven 3 without adding any command line options (e.g. configure a profile in `settings.xml`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from the maven documentation on [parallel builds](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/parallel-builds-in-maven-3.html).

Couple of related links (though not an answer to the question) are [jira issue related to this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3004) and a [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581465/maven-how-to-do-parallel-builds)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alias for your shell to do it

```
alias mvn='mvn -T4'
```