# compiling 10000 of java project simultaneously

Tags: java, compiler-construction, parallel-processing

Any one know how to compiling and run huge no of java project in simultaneously(assume request comming every time) can i use for sun jdk for this situation. is there way to distributed compilation?

Comment: What on earth would you want to do that for?

Comment: how do you track dependencies?

Comment: Why do you need to compile your code for every request?

Comment: He probably wants to provide binaries for all Java projects on GitHub ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ToolProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) api to start a compilation programmatically. (see [this tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html) for help)

With that as a starting point, you only need to create the proper abstraction to define what a project is (source folders, classpath etc.) and you have a thin frontend for compiling multiple projects.

I would probably use a ThreadPool to implement the actual compiling:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Or if you can't use threads, use a pool of compilers (or compiler holders) with a library like [commons / pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/).

Either way, you can have this workflow:

1. Request comes in
2. transform request to project definition
3. either request a free compiler or put the project in a queue
4. compile
5. return a handle to the compile job, so the client can poll the status asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

[Maven is starting to support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581465/maven-how-to-do-parallel-builds)... but why? In the time it takes to do a parallel build of Firefox (a typical, large C++ app) on say... a Core 2 Duo, you probably could build at least 5,000 independent Java apps so long as your build process was properly glued together.

(In the time it takes to build about a half dozen or so large C++ objects for Firefox on my MacBook Pro, I could probably build the entire CAS webapp which has a few hundred Java classes and about 12-18 Maven submodules)